# How to make pandas loop faster: scraping the text from url

Tags: python, pandas, performance, for-loop, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the text from articles in my website. I have a 'for' loop, but it works very slow. Are there any faster ways to do that? I've read about Pandas Built-In-Loop, vectorization and and numpy vectorization, but failed to apply it to my code.

```
def scarp_text(df):

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
session = requests.Session()

for j in range(0, len(df)):
    try:
        url = df['url'][j] #takes a url of an article in a column 'url'
        req = session.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    tags = soup.find_all('p')
    if tags == []:
        tags = soup.find_all('p', itemprop = 'articleBody')

    # Putting together all text from HTML p tags
    article = ''
    for p in paragraph_tags:
        article = article + ' ' + p.get_text()
        article = " ".join(article.split())

    df['article_text'][j] = article #put collected text to a corresponding cell

return df
```

Comment: Have you timed your inner loops to see what is the bottleneck here?

Comment: for the whole loop 54.2 ns ± 0.684 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

Comment: Which lines do you think I need to check?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 for loops, the most inner loop is usually the best place to start.
Plus operator is inefficient for string concatenation. Str.join is a better choice, it also takes a generator as input.

> article = " ".join(p.get_text() for p in paragraph_tags)
>
> article = " ".join(article.split())